# UIScrollView inside a UITableView won't show/hide correctly (Xcode iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've used Interface Builder to drop a UIScrollView into the top of a UITableView.
(To do some horizontal scrolling.)

In code, I now wish to selectively show/hide that UIScrollView.   I've connected it in IB, and then execute various combinations of code... but the area never disappears.

```
self.scrView.hidden = TRUE;
```

or:

```
CGRect aFrame       = self.scrView.frame;
aFrame.size.height  = 0;
[self.scrView setFrame:aFrame];
```

or:

```
[self.scrView setFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.scrView setContentSize:CGSizeZero];
```

or even the suggested:

```
[self.scrView removeFromSuperview];
```

Any way to make that thing disappear... including the area that it used to be in?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it from its parent view like this:

```
[self.scrView removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: Many tries (including that one) seem to make the "object" disappear... but the huge blank area stays there.   What is that... and how do I make it go away?

Comment: Was the scroll view in the same super view as the table view? Or did it have its own view controller.  The big white space sounds like there is a view or view controller with nothing else in it.

Comment: I'll have to look at the code... but I think the layout is:  A scrollView containing some images.  The scrollView is inside the top of a tableView... and that is inside the mainView.  I need to make the scrollView (and its contained images) disappear.  And NOT still leave behind the area where it used to be.